# How do I reuse variables in quoted line in a Vagrantfile?

Tags: ruby, syntax, vagrant, ansible

I'm putting together a Vagrantfile that can be used to spin up multiple VMs, it mostly works apart from the bit where I need to tell ansible which playbook to use. This is being imposed on top of an existing structure so there's little scope to change file locations and that.

Here's an extract of the relevant bits from my `Vagrantfile`:

```
hosts = [
 { name: 'myhost01',       hostname: 'vg-myhost01',    ip: '172.172.99.99', memory:'512',  cpu: 1, box: 'centos', port_forward: [] },
 ]

    config.vm.provision  :ansible do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = ['install/mydir/install_', :name, '.yml']
    end
```

Basically I'm trying to figure out how to get it to end up with a setting like

```
ansible.playbook = 'install/mydir/install_myhost01.yml'
```

but I can't seem to get the right syntax to get it to recognise `:name` as a variable in that context. It either tries to run `install_.yml`, `install_name.yml` or most commonly gives the error:

> `initialize': no implicit conversion of Symbol into String (TypeError)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more a question about Ruby syntax. You can use:

```
ansible.playbook = 'install/mydir/install_' + name + '.yml'
```

or (thanks to [Frédéric Henri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4296747/fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric-henri))

```
ansible.playbook = "install/mydir/install_#{name}.yml"
```

---

To reference the value from the hash (per OP's own suggestion):

```
ansible.playbook = "install/mydir/install_#{host[:name]}.yml"
```

Comment: about ruby syntax maybe "install/mydir/install_#{name}.yml" will be nicer

Comment: Indeed, looks and works nice :) Thank you, now I have to refactor a couple of my own files.

Comment: sorry about that .. but you'll be grateful when you'll be reading your code in cupple of months :)

Comment: So close, I tried that and got "undefined local variable" error, after a little more fiddling, I came up with this  "ansible.playbook = "install/mydir/install_#{host[:name]}.yml"" and that does the job. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see, I missed that part. Thanks for feedback, glad it worked for you.